# Build own authorization attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an application that needs authorization under Rights

Rights is very much (about 200, maybe there will be more)

One or several Rights can be assigned to one endpoint

Example:

```
[HasRights(Rights.AddPayer, Rights.DeletePayer)]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPayer([FromBody]PayerModel model)
{
}
```

I'm starting to build a class for the attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
    public class HasRightsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        HashSet<Rights> userRights;

        public HasRightsAttribute(params Rights[] rights)
        {
            userRights = rights.ToHashSet();
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            Claim claim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault();
            int userId = int.Parse(claim.Value);

            List<int> rights;

            using (var myContext = new myDB())
            {
                rights = (from UR in myContext.TblUserRole
                          join RR in myContext.TblRoleRight on UR.RoleID equals RR.RoleID
                          where UR.UserID == userId
                          select RR.RightID)
                          .ToList();
            }

            var permission = rights.Any(x => userRights.Contains((Rights)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Rights), x)));

            if (!permission)
            {
                //context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                Debug.WriteLine("NO ACCESS");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("YOU HAVE ACCESS");
            }
        }
    }
```

The attribute works. Is this a good direction?

I wanted to create the most simple way for Authorization

Comment: This seems very confusing... why would a `AddPayer` method need a `DeletePayer` right? Seems like you are trying to combine "roles" and "rights" into one giant enum... For example you should have a role, and that role has certain rights. Then a user can be assigned to one or more roles. Example roles would be "Administrator", "User", "Account Rep", etc... Rights would be "Add", "Delete", "Edit", etc.

Comment: @RonBeyer AddPayer and DeletePayer have been added to show that there can be more than one Right at endpoint. I did it because there are Roles and Rights but Roles will not be used. They are just to be divided into Rights categories. The application is already built and I have to add only authorization